# Setting the value of a parameter of a HTML form from a callback function

Tags: javascript, html, callback, forms, http-post

I have written this following piece of code with the help of different web sites. A snippet of the code is as follows:

```
function getLocation()
{
   var visitorGeolocation = new geolocate(false, true, 'visitorGeolocation');

//Check for cookie and run a callback function to execute after geolocation is read either from cookie or IPInfoDB API
   var callback = function()
    {
      var city=document.getElementById("city");
      city.value = visitorGeolocation.getField('cityName');
      alert('Visitor city name : ' + visitorGeolocation.getField('cityName'))
    };
visitorGeolocation.checkcookie(callback);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="getLocation()">
<form name="frm" method="post" action="result.jsp?page=1">
<input type="text" name="myQuery">
<input name="city" id="city" type="hidden" value="city">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want to pass the value of city silently while submitting the form so that I can get the value of city in result page. That's why I set its type as "hidden". But I cannot understand how to set the value of **city** while submitting the form, because I get value of city in a callback function as shown above. I have no clue how to do this.

I am new to web programming. I have very little idea about callback function. So if anyone helps me to solve this I will be really grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Excuse but alert('Visitor city name : ' + visitorGeolocation.getField('cityName')) print the city correct?

Comment: Yes Sir, it prints the city correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is a dilemma because there is a

1. `<input name="city" id="city" type="hidden" value="city">` with `value=city`
2. var city=document.getElementById("city");
                 city.value = visitorGeolocation.getField('cityName');

Then I suggest , remove `value="city"` inside `<input name="city" id="city" type="hidden">`, remove `name="submit" value="Submit"` or only `name="submit"` if you have to change the text's button.

Use this function :

```
function getLocation()
{
   var visitorGeolocation = new geolocate(false, true, 'visitorGeolocation');

//Check for cookie and run a callback function to execute after geolocation is read either from cookie or IPInfoDB API
   var callback = function()
    {
      document.getElementById("city").value = visitorGeolocation.getField('cityName');
      alert('Visitor city name : ' + visitorGeolocation.getField('cityName'));
    };
visitorGeolocation.checkcookie(callback);
}
```

Comment: Excuse but alert('Visitor city name : ' + visitorGeolocation.getField('cityName')) print the city correct?
 If this is a accepted answer put my answer how a accepted answer please...

Comment: Actually I have used ipinfodb.com to find geolocation. Thanks a lot, Sir :)

Comment: Thx to you that now I know this site ipinfodb.com and now on the my pc function,
You remember that you must have the key for using this script because without not function and has the city= undefined